# Android: No adapter attach

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am creating a listview in tabLayout. When I run the app in it says no adapter attach, skipping layout and I cannot see list in emulator; it appears blank. Please help me. I tried almost every answer on internet but could not make it.
I can see all other things except list ion the screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        private DatabaseReference myRef;

        private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
        private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
        private Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        bookList = new ArrayList<>();

        ClearAll();

        GetDataFromFirebase();

    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase() {
        Query query = myRef.child("Book");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                ClearAll();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Book book = new Book();

                    book.setImage(snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                    book.setTitle(snapshot.child("Title").getValue().toString());
                    book.setCat(snapshot.child("Cat").getValue().toString());

                    bookList.add(book);
                }
                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bookList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ClearAll(){
        if (bookList != null){
             bookList.clear();
             if (recyclerAdapter != null){
                 recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
        }

        bookList =  new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this warning because you haven't set `adapter` to `recycler view` in onCreate(). you have set adapter to recycler view inside
`addValueEventListener` that why adapter only attaching to recycler view when `onDataChange`  method triggers.

```
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter()        //Initialize adapter
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);        //set adapter
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: After loading the app splash screen, I got another error "App has stopped"

Answer (score 0):

first initialize the adapter with emptyList (bookList) in `onCreate()`,
and then when `onDataChange()` is called update `bookList` and call `recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as you have already done.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bookList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: It is not still working